# Cannot build react-native-xmpp library for IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, xmpp, xmppframework

I can use this library for Android with success but failed to use it in IOS. I have followed the official notes for installing this library and then install XMPPFramework pods and react-native-xmpp pods. But after that still I get one of the following errors:

1. Either I get core data model not found errors [issue#90](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-xmpp/issues/90) [total 6 errors] or
2. XMPPframework.h not found error - According to me, this errors is due to the same name collision of the XMPPFramework.h file found in the XMPPFramework and RNXMPP folder or
3. I get errors in KissXML Framework or
4. At last, if I mange to remove all the above errors, then I get the 'Linker failed error'.

Please help to provide the detailed documentation to use this library or if there is any alternative library for XMPP chat client that can be used in react-native for IOS. I have spent more than 2 weeks for searching the right solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 month ago I had the same task and then chose a [xmpp.js](http://xmppjs.org/client/) which I actually use on 3 environments in parallel right now:

- React Native
- Native Script
- Node.js

On React Native it works under iOS/Android

It does not use any 3rd party native code like react-native-xmpp lib (e.g. XMPPFramework for iOS), so it's only pure JS. Did not have any noticeable issues while integrating it, so can recommend to try

The complete step by step guide on how to use XMPP lib in React Native app is available here https://medium.com/@connectycube/xmpp-real-time-chat-in-react-native-8d6d5d23dd47

Comment: Is there any performance issue with it because by using xmpp.js everything will be on react-native side where as react-native-xmpp was using native environments so as to improve performance as react-native works on single javascript thread?

Comment: it uses await/async stuff inside. So I do no think you will see any reasonable performance glitches

Comment: Thanks. I will try that

Comment: Hi Rubycon, it will be very helpful, if you can provide some quick start react-native + xmpp.js code. Like how to add it in react-native and the code to send message to the server

Comment: I will give you a guide

Comment: Awesome, that will make my life. :)

Comment: Please provide the guide

Comment: Will provide it tomorrow morning

Comment: @Shubham1164 here is a guide https://medium.com/@connectycube/xmpp-real-time-chat-in-react-native-8d6d5d23dd47

Comment: Thanks buddy. This article is just published today. Just curious to know that, have u published it?

Comment: @Shubham1164 yes, I work with XMPP since 2010 and have lot's of stuff done already. Also I like Medium a lot, so if I see somebody needs something - I write a post so more people will use it in future and save some time

Comment: Hi Rubycon, can you please provide some documentation of all the available methods in the xmpp.js. I can't find it. Thanks

Comment: @Shubham1164 I can't find either. I built my apps by learning src code. Also, you can check for tests https://github.com/xmppjs/xmpp.js/tree/master/test

Comment: Bumping this one again, @Rubycon can you use XMPP protocol instead of WS when running it via RN ?

Comment: @ukaric what do you mean by "XMPP instead of WS"? WS is a transport protocol for XMPP (application) protocol

Comment: @Rubycon sorry for vague explanation what I ment is if I can use `XMPP://` instead of `WS://` or `WSS://` inside RN application that is running xmpp.js library ? Because when I do try to set it as XMPP it says that there no supported transit method.

Comment: No, this is wrong to use `XMPP://` - there is no any transit protocol like this. In XMPP apps - WS is used on the Web and TCP in mobile/node. Probably I did not get you - what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Rubycon, can you please help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53114492/3102733